# YouTube API Reflecting Wrong Content

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are trying to pull in posts for the hashtag #smartson on YouTube using the search endpoint in the v3 data API.

However, the following two posts are not appearing in the API results:

(1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F93wt8fZ-vE

(2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIWXU3IsssY

If you follow both those links and view the description section, you'll notice they both contain the hashtag #smartson as the very first word of the description. Yet they don't show up in the API results when searching that hashtag.

I can, however, retrieve those posts by looking up the channel in which they are published (using the YouTube channel endpoint). Here is the response I get back for those two posts:

```
    {  
       "kind":"youtube#searchResult",
       "etag":"\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/OIp6j6IiBd2nWkNA4H-3Dj6xGtw\"",
       "id":{  
          "kind":"youtube#video",
          "videoId":"BIWXU3IsssY"
       },
       "snippet":{  
          "publishedAt":"2017-06-05T10:47:48.000Z",
          "channelId":"UCYEsDVnEY3xiuuzDFW6g41w",
          "title":"clasohlsonworkwea",
          "description":"smartson #clasohlsonworkwear #testimonial Sitter jätte bra men lite för små knäskydd.",
          "thumbnails":{  
             "default":{  
                "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BIWXU3IsssY/default.jpg",
                "width":120,
                "height":90
             },
             "medium":{  
                "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BIWXU3IsssY/mqdefault.jpg",
                "width":320,
                "height":180
             },
             "high":{  
                "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BIWXU3IsssY/hqdefault.jpg",
                "width":480,
                "height":360
             }
          },
          "channelTitle":"Jörgen Lyckebay",
          "liveBroadcastContent":"none"
       }
    },
    {  
       "kind":"youtube#searchResult",
       "etag":"\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/CaSiQ6lYASTi7Eia0cHbF9Gwkz4\"",
       "id":{  
          "kind":"youtube#video",
          "videoId":"F93wt8fZ-vE"
       },
       "snippet":{  
          "publishedAt":"2017-06-05T08:21:06.000Z",
          "channelId":"UCYEsDVnEY3xiuuzDFW6g41w",
          "title":"clasohlsonworkwear",
          "description":"smartson #clasohlsonworkwear #testimonial Första testet med byxorna o klev på knapparna gör om som f..",
          "thumbnails":{  
             "default":{  
                "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F93wt8fZ-vE/default.jpg",
                "width":120,
                "height":90
             },
             "medium":{  
                "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F93wt8fZ-vE/mqdefault.jpg",
                "width":320,
                "height":180
             },
             "high":{  
                "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F93wt8fZ-vE/hqdefault.jpg",
                "width":480,
                "height":360
             }
          },
          "channelTitle":"Jörgen Lyckebay",
          "liveBroadcastContent":"none"
       }
    },
    {  
       "kind":"youtube#searchResult",
       "etag":"\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/EYuQkgOEkur8iziKcJuAx76XkmU\"",
       "id":{  
          "kind":"youtube#video",
          "videoId":"pW_RJqX0WGM"
       },
       "snippet":{  
          "publishedAt":"2017-04-26T15:41:54.000Z",
          "channelId":"UCYEsDVnEY3xiuuzDFW6g41w",
          "title":"Båt motor",
          "description":"Renoverad båtmotor 2.",
          "thumbnails":{  
             "default":{  
                "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pW_RJqX0WGM/default.jpg",
                "width":120,
                "height":90
             },
             "medium":{  
                "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pW_RJqX0WGM/mqdefault.jpg",
                "width":320,
                "height":180
             },
             "high":{  
                "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pW_RJqX0WGM/hqdefault.jpg",
                "width":480,
                "height":360
             }
          },
          "channelTitle":"Jörgen Lyckebay",
          "liveBroadcastContent":"none"
       }
}
```

In that API response, the description begins simply with the word "smartson," not the hashtag.

Any insight on why the API is not in sync with the public YouTube.com link?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Videos.list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419423/youtube-api-reflecting-wrong-content). Tried it and it doesn't ignore the hashtag.

Tried it in the API explorer and here's what I got:

```
"description": " . . .Tap tap tap.\n\n######tapper\n#hashtag\n#dont ignore\n##doublehashtag",
```

The youtube api returned the complete description, no omissions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, we are looking to pick up videos by #hashtag. The videos.list endpoint will, as I understand it, only give us back videos by id.